# Relative Layout overlaps

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Greatings everybody.

I was working on a simple custom ArrayAdapter when I bumped into an overlapping issue.

This is the xml of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@+id/label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that if the label is too long it overlaps the edittext element.

I have also tried using an horizontal layout with weights but the edittext gets out of the screen when the label is too long.

I have read like 6 posts about the relative layout overlapping but nothing seems to work.

Comment: set Fixed width instead of wrap content

Comment: but how can have a value that changes with the screen size?

Comment: why are you bothering about the screen size ? you are using 'dp(density independent pixels)' that name it self indicate that value will be changed on the screen size.. If you have any doubts regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android refer this

Answer (score 1):

Add android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label"   to your edit text.  That will make it always appear to the right of the label

Comment: This option overlaps when the text is too long